# Javascript - Add button with onClick attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code, which adds button:

```
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML=document.getElementById("items").innerHTML+
('<input type="button" value="'+document.getElementById("add").value+'"><br>');
```

It works. Now i am adding `onClick` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("items").innerHTML=document.getElementById("items").innerHTML+
    ('<input type="button" onClick="alert("'+document.getElementById("add").value+'")"
     value="'+document.getElementById("add").value+'"><br>');
```

I want to display an alert with button name (`add` is button id) if I click on button. But no alert displayed. Probably I made i mistake in `onClick`, because button is being added.
Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: That's probably the worst way to add an element imaginable ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do it the proper way

```
var items  = document.getElementById("items"),
    button = document.createElement('input'),
    br     = document.createElement('br'),
    add    = document.getElementById("add").value;

button.type  = 'button';
button.value = add;
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(add);
}, false);

items.appendChild(button);
items.appendChild(br);
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it.

Comment: Just a compatibility observation: In Internet Explorer, `addEventListener()` is only supported from version 9 and higher. I would suggest `button.onclick = function(){...}`.

Comment: @Kekas `onclick` only supports one event, whilst this allows multiple events. For older versions I believe `attachEvent` is what you would use.

Comment: Right, but if you only need one event, `onclick` should do the trick.

Comment: @Kekas - If old IE is an issue, you'd use `attachEvent`, and there are a million examples online on how to do that, so I wont write it all in the answer, but I believe that `addEventListener` should be used over `onclick` whenever possible, which is always.

Comment: Well, old IE is always an issue because lots of people still use IE8-, so you would care about compatibility when building a solution. The exact code you gave wouldn't work in IE8 for example. Does it seem right to you? To me it doesn't.

Comment: To me it seems perfect, if you need to support old IE there's an excellent polyfill available on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) but I'm not going to post a few hundred lines of code in the answer to show a polyfill for old browsers.

Comment: After getting some more experience, I understood that your solution is better. Thanks!

Comment: Saved my life tyty!!

Comment: Why is this way considered "proper"?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it!

```
 document.getElementById("items").innerHTML=document.getElementById("items").innerHTML
+('<input type="button" onClick="alert(\''+document.getElementById("add").value+'\')"
 value="'+document.getElementById("add").value+'"><br>')
```

I replaced `"` (double quote) with `\'` (single quote) in alert.
Works, button added, alert displayed.

Comment: Good for you, post your own answer when you're able to fix the issue, but this is still the most horid way to add an element ever invented, and you should consider rewriting it.